# Performance improvement in openMP

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

The following is the program to find Factorial of some given random number. Parallel when compared with serial, the performance of serial is far better even for large input. What should be apt logic to improve performance using openmp and how to further optimize the openmp parallelized code.

CODE -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>

int main( )
{
    int i,j,k,num,thread;
    int *arr,*result,temp;
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));
    scanf("%d",&num);
    arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
    result = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*num);

    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        arr[i]=rand()%10;
    }

    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        result[i]=1;
    }   

    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent_omp;
    double time_spent;

    begin = clock();
    /* here, do your time-consuming job */

        #pragma omp parallel for private(temp)
        for(j=0;j<num;j++){
            temp = arr[j];
            for(i=0;i<temp;temp--)
            result[j]=result[j]*temp;
        }   


    end = clock();
    time_spent_omp = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    /*
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        printf("%d\t%d\n",arr[i],result[i]);
    }*/

    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        result[i]=1;
    }   

    begin = clock();

    for(j=0;j<num;j++){
        temp = arr[j];
        for(i=0;i<temp;temp--)
        result[j]=result[j]*temp;
    }

    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin)/ CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    /*
    for(i=0;i<num;i++){
        printf("%d\t%d\n",arr[i],result[i]);
    }*/

    printf("Time for serial is %f\nTime for openMP is %f\n",time_spent, time_spent_omp);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT -

```
rnt@rnt-laptop:~/Desktop/C$ gcc -fopenmp -o fact fact.c
rnt@rnt-laptop:~/Desktop/C$ ./fact 
5
Time for serial is 0.000004
Time for openMP is 0.006214
rnt@rnt-laptop:~/Desktop/C$ ./fact 
11
Time for serial is 0.000013
Time for openMP is 0.000391
rnt@rnt-laptop:~/Desktop/C$ ./fact 
111
Time for serial is 0.000078
Time for openMP is 0.000507
rnt@rnt-laptop:~/Desktop/C$ ./fact 
1111
Time for serial is 0.000454
Time for openMP is 0.000860
rnt@rnt-laptop:~/Desktop/C$ ./fact 
11111
Time for serial is 0.002947
Time for openMP is 0.004829
rnt@rnt-laptop:~/Desktop/C$ ./fact 
111111
Time for serial is 0.022903
Time for openMP is 0.044273
rnt@rnt-laptop:~/Desktop/C$ ./fact 
1111111
Time for serial is 0.030446
Time for openMP is 0.160402
rnt@rnt-laptop:~/Desktop/C$ ./fact 
11111111
Time for serial is 0.298610
Time for openMP is 1.580710
rnt@rnt-laptop:~/Desktop/C$ ./fact 
111111111
Time for serial is 2.993646
Time for openMP is 13.202524
```

Comment: Do not use `clock` to measure time spent. See the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727849/no-performance-gain-after-using-openmp-on-a-program-optimize-for-sequential-runn?rq=1).

Comment: Furthermore, OP, you need to declare your loop iterators as private as well: it should be `#pragma omp parallel for private(j, temp, i)`. I'd be surprised if you were getting the correct output as-is.

Comment: I cantora belive I misses the loop iterators!

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll thanks for pointing out the error. Without using j and i as private i was getting correct output(dont know why) however using j and i as private I am getting speedup and the openmp runtime is less than the serial. I think j is by default private and there is no need to do it explicitly.

Comment: @R_Kapp using omp_get_wget along with private iterators is doing the trick. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(temp) schedule(static,XX)
```

with a several values of XX like 10, 50 100, 1000 etc...

By default, OpenMP uses dynamic scheduling that is better for parallelize code that would have balance issues between iterations/cores.

Edit: you need to put the loop iterators as private variables. Otherwise it will repeat work. You can experiment with different schedulers and vary parameters to tune thread performance still...

Comment: By default, the OpenMP schedule is implementation dependent. That being said, I'm also fairly certain that most implementations will implement `schedule(static, numIterations/numThreads)` as the default. I believe @R_Kapp has found the correct answer to this problem.

Comment: I have never seen a OpenMP implementation default to dynamic scheduling.